Lambda resolver not populating graphql field
I am trying to setup a graphql API using AWS Amplify which creates a notes system in which any authenticated user can create a note, as well as read any note created by a user that shares a cognito group with them.
I can see in the corresponding dynamoDB that the groups field is not being set, meaning that my fetch requests are returning an empty list.
I am using amplify gen 1 v6, and have been using these docs as reference, but am stuck on why it's not working and can't find any errors to go off.
I began with the schema:
type Todo @model @auth(rules: [
    { allow: groups, groupsField: "group"}
]) {
  id: ID!
  text: String!
  groups: [String] @function(name: "setGroupField-${env}")
}

but was getting authentication errors when creating, and so changed it to:
type Todo @model @auth(rules: [
    { allow: groups, groupsField: "group", operations: [update, read] }
    { allow: owner, operations: [create] }
]) {
  id: ID!
  text: String!
  groups: [String] @function(name: "setGroupField-${env}")
}

that fixed the authentication error when creating. I have also tried setting groups as a required field, and recieved errors that the create request did not fulfill the schema requirements.
I have the following setGroupField lambda resolver in both cases:
import json
import boto3

def handler(event, context):
    # Extract the username and groups from the identity information
    identity = event['identity']
    groups = identity['claims'].get('cognito:groups', [])
    
    print(groups)
    # Check if the user belongs to a group
    if not groups:
        raise Exception("User is not part of any group.")
    
    return groups

The print statement in the resolver has verified that it is successfully getting the correct groups.
Update:
I have tried using the Amplify generated UI components, which give the user the ability to set the group field (not something I want, but thought it would be worth a try) and it is now setting the group field, but to the user given value, not that returned by the lambda resolver.

I re-read through the new docs and noticed the statement:

While @model automatically generates dedicated "create", "read", "update", "delete", and "subscription" queries or mutations for you, there are some cases where you want to define a stand-alone query or mutation.

Changing my schema and lambda to the following creates the expected behaviour:
type Todo 
    @model(mutations: 
        { create: null, update: null, delete: null }
    )
    @auth(rules: [
        { allow: groups, groupsField: "group", operations: [read] }
        { allow: owner, operations: [create] }
    ])
{
  id: ID!
  text: String!
  group: String!
  owner: String!
  createdAt: AWSDateTime
}

input createTodoInput {
    text: String!
    group: String!
}

type Mutation {
    createTodoSecure(input: createTodoInput): Todo @function(name: "setGroupField-${env}")
}

import json
import boto3
from datetime import datetime
import uuid
import os

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table(os.environ['API_ACTIONSTAKEN_TODOTABLE_NAME'])

def handler(event, context):
    # Extract the username and groups from the identity information
    identity = event['identity']
    groups = identity['claims'].get('cognito:groups', [])
    username = identity['username']

    print(event)
    
    # Check if the user belongs to a group
    if not groups:
        raise Exception("User is not part of any group.")
    
    # Extract input fields
    input_data = event['arguments']['input']
    text = input_data['text']
    group = input_data['group']
    
    # Ensure the user is part of the specified group
    if group not in groups:
        raise Exception("User is not authorized to create a todo in this group.")
    
    # Generate a unique ID for the new todo item
    todo_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    
    # Prepare the item
    item = {
        'id': todo_id,
        'text': text,
        'group': group,
        'owner': username,
        'createdAt': datetime.utcnow().isoformat(timespec='seconds') + 'Z',
        'updatedAt': datetime.utcnow().isoformat(timespec='seconds') + 'Z',
        '_lastChangedAt': 0,
        '_version': 1,
    }

    # Write the item to DynamoDB
    table.put_item(Item=item)
    
    # Return the ID of the created todo item
    return item

